# setting image on UITabBar shows an extra line on Image

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, iphone-5

I am using a UITabBarController in my application (for iPhone 5). When i am trying to set an image on the TabBAr, the image shows a line. I have seen two questions similar to mine, but did not understand the solution.

Here's how I am adding the image:

```
UIImageView *tabBarView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_mypeople.png"]];

    tabBarView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -15, 320, 64);

    [tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:tabBarView];
```

The dimensions of my current image is 320X64 pixels. 
How to resolve this issue??

Comment: Have you tried with tabBarView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: If you are setting the tabBar frame y axis =  -15, then definitely it will lag the -15 pixels from the total height of the image. So actually you are getting your image displayed but the 15Pixel from bottom is making you a feel of extra line.

Can you set your frame as GCRectMake(0,0,320,64)

Comment: @KumarKl: Yes.. It does not work..

Comment: @BalramTiwari: The image is now being cut from bottom.. I there there is some problem with the size of my Image.. I am not sure what changes to make in size now..

Answer (score 2):

write this in appdelegate.m didfinishLanching method

```
UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bg"]
                          resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];

[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_select_indicator"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 and aboove the UITabBar has a shadow image, if you want to disable it you can just call `yourTabBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new]`.

In your case `tabBarController.tabBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new]`

Comment: any other suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to make it exact size.

Use this code if you are just using a `UITabBar` inside your view:

Type :1

```
UITabBar *tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 60)];
[self.view addSubview:tabBar];

UIImageView *tabBarView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBar.png"]];
tabBar.backgroundImage = tabBarView.image;
```

Presently my image size is 320 x 5

Type 2:

If you are using a `UITabBarController` then use it like this

```
UIImageView *tabBarView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBar.png"]];

UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
tabController.tabBar.backgroundImage = tabBarView.image;
```

Here are the screen shot for both.

[image: Type 1]

[image: Type 2]

Comment: My Image is BlueColor.